# TypeScript compiler failing on a mac

Tags: gruntjs, typescript, nvm, tsc, typescript1.4

Typescript compilation task works fine on linux machines but on a mac fails with the following not particularly useful error message and what looks like a binary dump.

```
$ grunt
Running "ts:build" (ts) task
Compiling...
Fast compile will not work when --out is specified. Ignoring fast compilation
Using tsc v1.4.1
������������=��AF���=����

>> Error: tsc return code: 3
Warning: Task "ts:build" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Im using nvm with node v0.11.4 and rvm with ruby v2.2.0.

Any ideas how to fix this, or even debug?

Comment: I see that you are using `grunt` — are you using the `grunt-typescript` package to plug the TypeScript compiler?

Comment: Seems that is't more like `grunt-ts`.

Comment: Nick, can you please provide the relevant part of your `Gruntfile`?

Comment: I tried this with both grunt-ts and grunt-typescript both of which failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with a malfunctioning node installation. I upgraded to node 0.12 which fixed the problem.

Just to check the problem wasn't node 0.11.4 specific I removed all previous versions of node and reinstalled 0.11.4 and the error no longer occurs.

I took these steps after removing all node modules, clearing the cache and reinstalling with no luck. I also tried using multiple typescript compiler versions.

Answer (score 2):

As the question includes debugging, here are some pointers which might help determine where the problem is.

- Try compiling from the command line with `tsc` alone (no grunt), in case the problem is with grunt or the `ts:build` task (looks like `grunt-ts`).
- Maybe one of your source files is causing the tools to crash (perhaps they can't cope with a file's encoding?). If a single, simple file will compile, then try removing subsets of your source from the build. If some of those files are causing the crash (whether valid TypeScript or not) you may be able to find a temporary workaround.
- Try compiling with different versions of `tsc`. If you need 1.4.1 features you could try using the latest from https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript (see [here](https://github.com/TypeStrong/grunt-ts#compiler) for how to do this with `grunt-ts`).

Comment: This is a comment, providing direction, not an answer.  Please post it as a comment when you can.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I had already tried with a few different versions of the `tsc`.  It turned out typescript was failing outside of grunt (something I probably should have checked earlier)